# How to pass external variables to the wp_new_user_notification_email filter?

Tags: customization, users, email, user-registration

We're trying to customize the default e-mail new users receive when registering on our website. For this, we are using the wp_new_user_notification_email filter added in WP4.9.0

For our functions.php file not to be cluttered we have the template for the email in "templates/email_welcome.php". We need to load this file to build the $message variable but the content returned is always empty.

Here's what we have added in our child-theme functions.php

```
// =================================================
// Set custom new user e-mail notification template
// =================================================
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 999, 3 );

function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $userEmail  = stripslashes( $user->user_email );
    $user_login = $user->user_login;
    $siteUrl    = get_site_url();
    $logoUrl    = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'android-chrome-192x192.png';
    $key = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_activation_key FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_login = %s", $user_login));
    if ( empty($key) ) {
        // Generate something random for a key...
        $key = wp_generate_password(20, false);
        do_action('retrieve_password_key', $user_login, $key);
        // Now insert the new md5 key into the db
        $wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array('user_activation_key' => $key), array('user_login' => $user_login));
    }
    $rplink     = '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user->user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n";

    ob_start();
    include get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/templates/email_welcome.php';
    $message = ob_get_clean();

    $wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = sprintf( 'Welcome to Site.com' );
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = $message;
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['headers'] = 'Content-Type: text/html';

    return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. We also tried to reference a function instead..

```
function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {
    $message = wpse5427_new_user_custom_content_html($user);

    $wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = sprintf( 'Welcome to Site.com' );
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = $message;
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['headers'] = 'Content-Type: text/html';

    return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}

function wpse5427_new_user_custom_content_html($user) {
    global $wpdb;
    $userEmail  = stripslashes( $user->user_email );
    $user_login = $user->user_login;
    $siteUrl    = get_site_url();
    $logoUrl    = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . 'android-chrome-192x192.png';
    $key = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_activation_key FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_login = %s", $user_login));
    if ( empty($key) ) {
        // Generate something random for a key...
        $key = wp_generate_password(20, false);
        do_action('retrieve_password_key', $user_login, $key);
        // Now insert the new md5 key into the db
        $wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array('user_activation_key' => $key), array('user_login' => $user_login));
    }
    $rplink     = '<' . network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user->user_login), 'login') . ">\r\n";

    ob_start();
    include get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/templates/email_welcome.php';
    $message = ob_get_clean();

    return $message;
}
```

But this doesn't work either. Is it possible at all to include an external file in a filter like that?

Here's the content for email_welcome.php:

```
<?php
// =================================================
// Custom new user notification template
// =================================================
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
?>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family:"Open sans",sans-serif;
}

h1 {
    color:#111;
    font-family:"Raleway",sans-serif;
    font-weight:700;
    margin-top:0;
    text-align:center;
}

.main-content-wrapper{
    max-width:800px;
    margin:50px auto;
    background:#fff;
    border:#333 3px solid;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
}

.site-logo{
    text-align:center;
    background:#333;
    padding:10px;
}

.site-logo img{
}

.main-content{
    padding:30px 50px;
}

.email-footer {
    max-width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    color:#bbb;
    font-size:80%;
}

.email-button {
    display:inline-block;
    background:#ea640f;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:15px 30px;
    margin:20px auto 30px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:#ea640f 2px solid;
    border-radius:3px;
}

</style>

<div class="main-content-wrapper">
    <div class="site-logo">
    <img src="<?php echo $logoUrl; ?>" alt="Site.com"/>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
<h1>Welcome to Site</h1>
    <p style="margin-top:30px;">
    <?php if ( $user->first_name != '' ) : ?>
        Thank you for joining us <?php echo $user->first_name; ?>.
        </p>
        <p>
        You're only steps away from completing your account creation!
        </p>
    <?php else : ?>
        You're only steps away from completing your account creation!
        </p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <p>
        Please reset your password using the button below
    </p>
        <a href="<?php echo $rplink; ?>" class="email-button">Reset Password</a>
        <br>
        <strong>Sincerely,</strong><br>
        The Site Team
    </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="email-footer">
© 2019 Site.com – All Rights Reserved.
</div>
```

Thank you!

---

**EDIT:** For those of you looking to do the same thing, here's a working code:

```
// =================================================
// Set custom new user e-mail notification template
// =================================================
add_filter( 'wp_new_user_notification_email', 'custom_wp_new_user_notification_email', 999, 3 );

function custom_wp_new_user_notification_email( $wp_new_user_notification_email, $user, $blogname ) {   
    global $wpdb;

    $userEmail  = stripslashes( $user->user_email );
    $user_login = $user->user_login;
    $siteUrl    = get_site_url();
    $logoUrl    = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/android-chrome-192x192.png';

    // Generate something random for a key...
    $key = wp_generate_password(20, false);
    do_action('retrieve_password_key', $user_login, $key);
    // Now insert the key, hashed, into the DB.
    if ( empty( $wp_hasher ) ) {
            require_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php';
            $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash( 8, true );
    }
    $hashed = time() . ':' . $wp_hasher->HashPassword( $key );
    $wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array('user_activation_key' => $hashed ), array( 'user_login' => $user->user_login ) );

    $rplink     = network_site_url("wp-login.php?action=rp&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user->user_login), 'login');

    ob_start();
    include get_stylesheet_directory() . '/templates/email_welcome.php';
    $message = ob_get_clean();

    $wp_new_user_notification_email['subject'] = sprintf( 'Welcome to Site.com' );
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['message'] = $message;
    $wp_new_user_notification_email['headers'] = 'Content-Type: text/html';

    return $wp_new_user_notification_email;
}
```

Here's the update template for email_welcome.php:

```
<?php
// =================================================
// Custom new user notification template
// =================================================
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;
?>
<div style='font-family:"Open sans",sans-serif;background-color: #f2f2f2;padding:50px;'>
    <div style="max-width:800px;margin:0 auto;background:#fff;border:#333 3px solid;border-radius:5px;text-align:center;">
        <div style="text-align:center;background:#333;padding:5px 5px 2px;">
            <img src="<?php echo $logoUrl; ?>" alt="Site.com" style="height:45px;">
        </div>
        <div style="padding:30px 50px;">
            <h1 style='color:#111;font-family:"Raleway",sans-serif;font-weight:700;margin-top:0;text-align:center;'>Welcome to Site</h1>
            <p style="margin-top:30px;">
            <?php if ( $user->first_name != '' ) : ?>
                Thank you for joining us <?php echo $user->first_name; ?>.
                </p>
                <p>
                You're only steps away from completing your account creation!
                </p>
            <?php else : ?>
                You're only steps away from completing your account creation!
                </p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <p>
                Please reset your password using the button below
            </p>
                <a href="<?php echo $rplink; ?>" style="display:inline-block;background:#ea640f;text-transform:uppercase;text-decoration:none;padding:15px 30px;margin:20px auto 30px;color:#fff;font-weight:bold;border:#ea640f 2px solid;border-radius:3px;">Reset Password</a>
                <br>
                <strong>Sincerely,</strong><br>
                The Site Team
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="max-width:800px;margin:30px auto 0;text-align:center;color:#bbb;font-size:80%;">
    © 2019 Site.com – All Rights Reserved.
    </div>
</div>
```

*Note 1: If you use any plugin that interacts with the login/registration process, this may not work at all. If you have issues, test with all plugins disabled and re-enable them one by one.*

*Note 2: The below solution uses an e-mail template email_welcome.php located in the "/templates" folder of your theme.*

*Note 3: Code was updated to always regenerate $key to allow pretty links and store the hashed $key as it's the case in the WP function.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is you're using [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory_uri/) function in an attempt to include a file. This function returns a URL when what you want to do when you need to include a file is provide a path. You could be using instead is [`get_stylesheet_directory()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_stylesheet_directory/)

Here's what the output would look like:

```
// - https://yourwebsite.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/
$url = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();

// - \www\httpdocs\wp-content\themes\my-theme\
$directory = get_stylesheet_directory();
```

Comment: Good catch, it worked like a charm!
Our classes got wrecked by Gmail but that's another issue and I kind of expected that. Adding the style directly inline might be a better option. Thanks again for your help!